# How to use template refs in Nuxt 3

Tags: vue.js, nuxt.js, vuejs3, nuxtjs3

In Nuxt2 there were [template $refs](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/components-edge-cases.html#Accessing-Child-Component-Instances-amp-Child-Elements) that you could access in `<script>` with `this.$refs`

I would like to know what is the Nuxt3 equivalent of this is.

I need this to access the innerText of an element. I am not allowed to use `querySelector` or `getElementById` etc.

This is the way we write code. I can give html elements `ref="fooBar"` but I can't access it with `this.$refs.fooBar` or even `this.$refs`.

```html
<script setup lang="ts">
import { ref, computed } from 'vue';

const foo = ref('bar');

function fooBar() {
  //Do stuff
}
</script>

<template>
  //Html here
</template>
```

Comment: In this example `const foo = ref('bar');` is instead of `data() {return {foo:'bar'}}`

Answer (score 11, accepted):

With Options API

```html
<script>
export default {
  mounted() {
    console.log('input', this.$refs['my-cool-div'])
  }
}
</script>

<template>
  <div ref="my-cool-div">
    hello there
  </div>
</template>
```

With Composition API

```html
<script setup>
const myCoolDiv = ref(null)

const clickMe = () => console.log(myCoolDiv)
</script>

<template>
  <button @click="clickMe">show me the ref</button>
  <div ref="myCoolDiv">
    hello there
  </div>
</template>
```

Comment: This is not at all how my code looks like anymore i thought that this was because of Nuxt3 but maybe because we work in TypeScript? We don’t use any lifecycle hooks anymore i’ve updated the question with my code.

Comment: Aaaah yes that works thanks for like the 8th time you safe my life. So this way of using refs is not a nuxt3 thing but just typescript? I'm new to both.

Comment: @MarnixElling this is actually a Vue3 (Composition API) thing: https://vuejs.org/api/composition-api-lifecycle.html#onmounted If you want to type it properly, here you go: https://vuejs.org/guide/typescript/composition-api.html#typing-component-template-refs